# Whats the best way to combine data in PHP for inserting into SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I'm fairly new to PHP and am trying to combine data before inserting into SQL, I know what I have to add but am having trouble thinking of the best way to insert it into the DB. Basically I want it to look like this when I echo it to the screen. Just so I can visualize it before inserting it.

```
"music_work_ID": "19"
"position": "1" 
"duration": ["1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0"]
"music_tag_ID": [ "3", "5" ]
```

but at the moment it looks like this

```
"music_work_ID": "19", "positon": "1", "duration": [ { "isDuration1": "1", "0": "1", "isDuration3": "0", "1": "0", "isDuration5": "1", "2": "1", "isDuration10": "1", "3": "1", "isDuration15": "0", "4": "0", "isDuration20": "0", "5": "0" } ], "music_tag_ID": [ "3", "5" ]
```

The code I wrote to get the data is below

```
function duration_get($userID_selection) {

          $conn = connect();
          
          try {
            $sql = "SELECT isDuration1, isDuration3, isDuration5, isDuration10 ,isDuration15, 
            isDuration20 FROM music_work WHERE music_work_ID = :userID_selection ";
        
            $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam(':userID_selection', $userID_selection, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            
            $statement->execute();
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
        
            $conn = null;
          }
          catch(PDOException $e)
          {
            echo $e->getMessage();
          }
          return $data;
        }

        header('Content-type: Application/JSON');
        $work_data = music_work_get(); 
        $userInput = array();
        $id = $_POST['music_work_ID'];

        $recieved = duration_get($id);

        $userInput['music_work_ID'] = $_POST['music_work_ID'];
        $userInput['positon'] = $_POST['position'];
        $userInput['duration'] = $recieved;

        if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
          if(!empty($_POST["checkbox"])){
            $userInput['music_tag_ID'] = $_POST["checkbox"];
        }
```

Comment: You can try `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($userInput); echo '</pre>';` Not sure if the output is for you (dev) or for a production site for real users.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your question? Is the issue with the way the data is formatted / presented to you in the browser or is the issue with the way you are processing the data?

Comment: "Numbered" column names are usually a sign that you are doing things wrong to begin with, and should properly _normalize_ your data model first of all.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to add pass PDO::FETCH_ASSOC as an argument into fetchAll() to get rid of the duplicate data that was in the    duration array. The code below fixed the issue

```
 <?php
        
        /* duration_get is to get only the durations associated with the music_work */
        function duration_get($userID_selection) {

          $conn = connect();
          
          try {
            $sql = "SELECT isDuration1, isDuration3, isDuration5, isDuration10 ,isDuration15, 
            isDuration20 FROM music_work WHERE music_work_ID = :userID_selection ";
        
            $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam(':userID_selection', $userID_selection, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            
            $statement->execute();
            $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
            $conn = null;
          }
          catch(PDOException $e)
          {
            echo $e->getMessage();
          }
          return $data;
        }

        header('Content-type: Application/JSON');
        $work_data = music_work_get(); 
        $userInput = array();
        $duration_data = duration_get($_POST['music_work_ID']);

        // What happens when the user hits insert
        if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
          $dur_array = array();
          $userInput['music_work_ID'] = $_POST['music_work_ID'];
          $userInput['position'] = $_POST['position'];
          $userInput['duration'] = $duration_data;
          
          // Loops through the current 'duration' array to get only the values
          foreach ($userInput['duration'] as $array){
            foreach ($array as $k => $v){
              if ($v === '0'){
                unset($userInput[$k]);
              } else {
                array_push($dur_array, substr($k,10)); // adds the values to a new array declared above
              }
            }
          }
          
          $userInput['duration'] = $dur_array; // assigns the values of dur_array to the current array for easy reading

          if(!empty($_POST["checkbox"])){
            $userInput['music_tag_ID'] = $_POST["checkbox"]; // gets the checkboxes that have been checked and adds them to array
          }

          music_movement_add($userInput);

        } else if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            music_work_delete($userID_selection);
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
        }


        ?>
```

Instead of this JSON that was displayed before

```
"music_work_ID": "19", "positon": "1", "duration": [ { "isDuration1": "1", "0": "1", "isDuration3": "0", "1": "0", "isDuration5": "1", "2": "1", "isDuration10": "1", "3": "1", "isDuration15": "0", "4": "0", "isDuration20": "0", "5": "0" } ], "music_tag_ID": [ "3", "5" ]
```

It now displays this much cleaner array that I can use to loop through and add to the DB

```
Array
(
    [music_work_ID] => 19
    [position] => 1
    [duration] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 10
        )

    [music_tag_ID] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )

)
```